# How can I execute this sql statement with .NET and Dapper.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, dapper

I have the following sql query:

```
BEGIN TRAN;

UPDATE [dbo].[Foo] SET StatusType = 2 WHERE FooId = xxx;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[FooNotes] (FooId, Note) VALUES ('blah....', xxx);

ROLLBACK TRAN;
```

and this is for a list of id's. 
eg.

```
var fooIds = new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
```

so then I expect this..

```
BEGIN TRAN;

UPDATE [dbo].[Foo] SET StatusType = 2 WHERE FooId = 1;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[FooNotes] (FooId, Note) VALUES ('blah....', 1);

UPDATE [dbo].[Foo] SET StatusType = 2 WHERE FooId = 2;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[FooNotes] (FooId, Note) VALUES ('blah....', 2);

UPDATE [dbo].[Foo] SET StatusType = 2 WHERE FooId = 3;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[FooNotes] (FooId, Note) VALUES ('blah....', 3);

ROLLBACK TRAN;
```

Can this be done with [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net)?

NOTE: If the `TRAN` makes this hard, I can drop that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dapper has only minimal support for *altering* queries internally (it supports list expansion for `IN`, literal injection, and some `OPTION`/`UNKNOWN` tweaks. You have two options here:

1. use `StringBuilder` to create a single large operation that you can execute (this can be parameterized via a dictionary)
2. move the transaction to ADO.NET rather than TSQL

For the latter, perhaps something like:

```
using(var tran = conn.BeginTransaction())
{
    try
    {
        conn.Execute(@"
UPDATE [dbo].[Foo] SET StatusType = 2 WHERE FooId = @id;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[FooNotes] (FooId, Note) VALUES ('blah....', @id);",
            fooIds.Select(id => new { id }), transaction: tran);
    }
    finally // in this example, we always want to rollback
    {
        tran.Rollback();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah ok - so I'm trying to grok this .... so this is using Dapper still, but the tran is created manually (instead of in the query) which dapper 'uses' because dapper's just :sparkles: on the existing connection?

Comment: @Pure.Krome No sparkles required - we're explicitly passing the transaction in as a parameter

Comment: Ah yeah, I missed the last param when I was reviewing the code snippet, above. Simple - makes perfect sense. cheers! :heart: your work Marc - keep fighting the good fight :) :) :cheers:

Comment: Oh - and I have to manually `conn.Open()` before I create the transaction scope (based on your comment in the other answer in this thread)?

Comment: @Pure that isn't a "transaction scope" - it is an ADO.NET transaction. "Transaction scope" is a separate but related concept. But yes, the connection would need to be open to begin a transaction.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var tx = connection.BeginTransaction())
    {
        foreach (var fooId in fooIds)
        {
            connection.Execute("UPDATE [dbo].[Foo] SET StatusType = 2 WHERE FooId = @id; INSERT INTO [dbo].[FooNotes] (FooId, Note) VALUES ('blah....', @id);", new {id = fooId}, tx);
        }

        tx.Rollback();
    }
}
```

Comment: Minor ADO.NET nuisance: you can't `connection.BeginTransaction()` until you `connection.Open()`

Comment: this would do 2 x `fooIds.Count` round trips to the DB, instead of one trip to the db?